# Get and edit the hidden_field_tag array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a hidden_field_tag in a form to pass an array of flags (0 or 1) with length @tags. When the page loads, the flags are all 0, but when something happen I want to update one index value, so it's 1 after some trigger action.

So, summing up, in my view I've got something like this:

```
- @tags.each do |tag|
  = hidden_field_tag "tags[]", 0
```

And in my .js I want to be able to edit one value from that array.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution:

Changed

```
- @tags.each do |tag|
  = hidden_field_tag "tags[]", 0
```

To

```
- @tags.each do |tag|
  = hidden_field_tag "tags[]", 0, id: "tag_"+tag.id
```